# How to catch exception thrown by configurations.testPlugins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, dsl

I am trying to use the following code to check if not Jenkins plugin files exist in artifactory

However, configurations.testPlugins throws exception and exit once it can get some file from artifactory.

Is it possible to catch the exceptions and keep it running until all files have been verified?

Is there any document/example on testPlugins?

Thanks!

```
task resolveTestPlugins(type: Copy) {
from configurations.testPlugins
into new File(sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir, 'test-dependencies')
include '*.hpi'
include '*.jpi'
def mapping = [:]

doFirst {
    configurations.testPlugins.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
        mapping[it.file.name] = "${it.name}.${it.extension}"
    }
}
rename { mapping[it] }

doLast {
    List<String> baseNames = source*.name.collect { mapping[it] }.collect { it[0..it.lastIndexOf('.') - 1] }
    new File(destinationDir, 'index').setText(baseNames.join('\n'), 'UTF-8')
}
```

}

The following is the updated code (debug purpose) with try catch and error.

```
task resolveTestPlugins(type: Copy) {

configurations.each { println it.name }

println configurations.testPlugins 

try {
// Line 88
configurations.testPlugins.each {
    println it.name
}
} catch(Exception e) {
    println "Failed : " + e
}

try {
from configurations.testPlugins
into new File(sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir, 'test-dependencies')
include '*.hpi'
include '*.jpi'
} catch(Exception e) {
    println "Failed : " + e
}

def mapping = [:]

def pluginname = ""

doFirst {       
    try {
        println "A-------- : " + pluginname
        configurations.testPlugins.each {

            try {
                println "B-------- : " + pluginname
                it.resolvedConfiguration.each {
                    try {
                        println "C-------- : " + pluginname

                    it.resolvedArtifacts.each{
                        pluginname = "${it.name}.${it.extension}"
                        println "D-------- : " + pluginname
                        executeBuildCommand(commandString, component)
                        mapping[it.file.name] = "${it.name}.${it.extension}"
                    }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        println "Failed : " + pluginname
                    }       
                }   
            } catch(Exception e) {
                println "Failed : " + e
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        println "Failed : " + e
    }

    /*      
    try {
        configurations.testPlugins.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
            pluginname = "${it.name}.${it.extension}"
            println "-------- : " + pluginname
            executeBuildCommand(commandString, component)
            mapping[it.file.name] = "${it.name}.${it.extension}"
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        println "Failed : " + pluginname
    }
    */
}

rename { mapping[it] }

doLast {
try {   
    List<String> baseNames = source*.name.collect { mapping[it] }.collect { it[0..it.lastIndexOf('.') - 1] }
    new File(destinationDir, 'index').setText(baseNames.join('\n'), 'UTF-8')

} catch(ResolveException  e) {
    println "Failed : " + e
} catch(Exception  e) {
    println "Failed : " + e
}
}
```

}

The following is the exception. The build stops once there is a exception. Not sure if it could keep running until all plugins have been checked. 
Thanks!

```
         Failed : org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testPlugins'.

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where:
 Build file 'C:\...\...\build.gradle' line: 88

 * What went wrong:
 Could not determine the dependencies of task ':resolveTestPlugins'.
 > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testPlugins'.
    > Could not determine artifacts for org.jenkins-ci.plugins:git-server:1.5
       > Could not get resource 'https://.../artifactory/libs-release/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/git-server/1.5/git-server-1.5.hpi'.
          > Could not HEAD 'https://.../artifactory/libs-release/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/git-server/1.5/git-server-1.5.hpi'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Comment: Have you tried `try`/`catch`? You should see in the log, which kind of exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes. please review my updated question.

Comment: I don't see any update.

Comment: Sorry. just updated.